# Using RequestDispatcher to forward to the same page that send request

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have a servlet, which is called "LoginServlet", an index.jsp, which has the login form (username & password). I send the request to the LoginServlet, and used:

```
getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

To go back to the index.jsp with the username and user information (To display Welcome XXX on top right of the screen). The problem is, I cannot use ${requestScope.userName} to retrieve the username. The userName simply does not exist in the request. However, when I dispatched to another jsp page, it did receive the request with new information and I could retrieve it.

I want to know is there a way to forward to the same page which send the request? I simply cannot get the data dispatched from servlet to the same page, i.e. for making user logged in

Comment: You've apparently already the answer. What's now the question?

Comment: I want to know is there a way to forward to the same page which send the request. I simply cannot get the data dispatched from servlet to the same page, i.e. for making user logged in.

Comment: Ah yes that was the question (please add it to your post, in a clear and concise sentence with a "?" in the end which sums up the concrete problem). As to the concrete problem, did you consider the session scope? It's a normal practice to store the logged-in `User` in the session scope since that's been used to check if any user is logged in or not (so that you can block or allow access in a Filter class).

Comment: Well it's just an example. I am required to use requestScope to pass data around, not just log in, to minimise the load, except for things like shopping cart.